# Convert .env file to object list using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

Using Terragrunt, I am trying to provision a Terraform module which has the following variable:

```
variable "param_list" {
  type = list(object({
    name  = string
    type  = string
    value = string
  }))
  description = "List of environment variables."
}
```

The application that is responsible for provisioning the module contains .env files

```
.env       -- Baseline
.env.local -- Local environment
.env.qa    -- All QA environments
.env.qa.qa1-- All QA1 specific environments
```

These files look like:

```
PRODUCTION="false"
APP_URL="app.localhost.com"
SOME_KEY="abc=123"
...
```

Any environment variable in baseline is applied to all environments. These can be overwritten by specific configurations. For example, if the above snippet was for baseline and .env.qa contained:

```
APP_URL="app.qa.com"
```

Then the APP_URL should be app.qa.com for all qa environments. If it did not contain APP_URL it would just use "app.localhost.com".

When Terragrunt is called the environment type (e.g. qa) and the specific environment (e.g. qa1) are set in locals variables:

```
locals {
  env_name = get_env("ENV_NAME")
  env_type = trim(local.env_name, "1234567890")
}
```

How do I convert the .env file to a list of objects using Terraform and supply it as a param for the module? This should happen in a terragrunt.hcl file. If possible, I would rather contain the logic to this file and not use a bash script to convert the file beforehand.

Note: The terraform module pushes the param_list to the AWS param store. The name is the key (PRODUCTION) and the value would be (false). Type will always be string for this case (secure strings will be handled separately for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this via this function incase anyone else is trying to do something similar. This only creates a map as opposed to a list of objects however could be converted. I updated the module to accept a map since I am not using secure strings for this at the moment so type will always be the same.

```
locals {      
      env_files = [
        "${local.env_files_dir}.env.tfvars",
        "${local.env_files_dir}.env.${local.env_type}.tfvars",
        "${local.env_files_dir}.env.${local.env_type}.${local.env_name}.tfvars"
      ]
      param_list = merge([
        for filename in local.env_files : {
          for param in [
            for param in split("\n", file(filename)) :
            regex("^([^=]+)=\"(.*)\"|([^\"].*)$", param) if trimspace(param) != ""
          ] :
          param[0] => replace(coalesce(param[1], param[2], "empty-value"), "<<env>>", "${local.env_name}")
        }
        if fileexists(filename)
      ]...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This idea of "env files" is not a standard format documented in a specification, so each library that supports it in different languages has different expectations for exactly how the file should be formatted and how it should be interpreted. If these files are also being used by something *other than* Terraform then you'll have two main options:

1. Implement something equivalent to what your other existing env file parser does to parse the contents of the file in the Terraform language, using expressions.
2. Use something like [the `hashicorp/external` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external), with [the `external` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external), to run an external program written in the same language as your application which uses the same "env file" parsing library and then prints out the result in the form the data source expects. For the `external` data source in particular, that would be a JSON object with string values for all of the properties.

Although I would typically consider running external software to be a last resort, in this particular case I would prefer the second option because it then guarantees that the files will be interpreted in exactly the same way as the application itself would interpret them, due to using exactly the same library to parse the files. You won't be able to use this option directly inside a Terragrunt configuration file though, because data sources are a feature of Terraform itself rather than of Terragrunt.

The first option is possible but significantly more complicated. Here are some building blocks that can help when writing custom parsers in the Terraform language, but the Terraform language is not designed for performing this sort of general computation and so the resulting expressions tend to be complicated and hard to maintain:

- [`split`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/split) for breaking the input into smaller chunks by a delimiter, such as splitting each file into a list of strings where each string is one line from the input file.
- [`regex`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/regex) for extracting subpatterns from a string using a regular expression. For example, this might be the most straightforward way to extract the key and value parts from each line of your input.
- [`for` expressions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) for creating one list from another list by evaluating a expressions for each item in the source list. For example, you could apply `regex` to each item in the list of single lines created by `split`.

Terragrunt's language does not have all of the same capabilities as Terraform's own language. I've answered above based on my knowledge of the main Terraform language and I don't know whether the functions I mentioned are available in Terragrunt's language.

Comment: I understand env files are not treated the same however not important here since I was just asking how to store them in the param store, the injection of these at run time is handled outside of this (in this case no data conversion needed to take place anyway.) I was giving context because it seemed like a common use case. I know about those expressions as well, it was putting them together which was the challenge and I was hoping someone could help me out. Anyway, was able to solve it have posted the solution.